# How to use fsyncLock() safely in backing up a single mongod

Tags: mongodb, backup

I read from mongodb document:

```
important:
db.fsyncLock() may block reads, including those necessary to verify authentication
warning:
When calling db.fsyncLock(), ensure that the connection is kept open to allow a subsequent call to db.fsyncUnlock(). Closing the connection may make it difficult to release the lock.
```

In worst case, I use fsyncLock() to block database and suddenly lost connection to database (because of temporary network failure). I cannot reconnect because fsyncLock() block reader. My database will be blocked forever.

I am considering to shutdown mongodb to backup.

What is the most safest backup solution for single mongod ?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a filesystem based snapshot (like [LVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_(Linux)), [EBS](http://aws.amazon.com/ebs/) or similar) - as long as the snapshot is point-in-time and includes the [journal](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/journaling/) then you do not need to lock the database at all when taking a backup.  Once the snapshot is complete, simply archive it off to your backup drive/host/cloud and then remove the snapshot.

Other options would require this to be a replica set. With a single node replica set you could use [MMS backup](https://mms.mongodb.com/) (no other hosts required, but you do have to have [an oplog](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/), and it is not free).

If you added a second node (and an arbiter to break ties in voting), then your secondary could function as your backup.  You could take it down to make a backup without impacting your original node (again, as long as you have an arbiter), or you could use the techniques above also

Comment: Thank you for your time. I have an other question. If two mongod are same version, should I sync physically data files and namespace file to destination mongod ?

Comment: The on disk format has been the same for as many versions as I can remember, there will be a new format with the WiredTiger storage engine in 2.8 but until then, if you copy the data files (data and namespace files) for a database between different instances they will be usable, yes.